# Networking “does not have a valid IP configuration” - all known solutions exhausted

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ip

A lot of people get this error for different reasons, but on 1 particular high-end laptop the error has persisted for a full year, despite trying everything short of reinstalling the OS. It seems like nothing special was happening when the error began, though some network related programs were installed (since removed).

Here’s a list of what has been tried:

- Restarting
- Disabling / enabling the network adapters
- netsh resets and flushing (e.g int tcp reset, int ip reset, flushdns, etc)
- Reinstalling network/WiFi drivers
- Changing networks many times to make sure it has nothing to do with the router
- Manually and automatically setting LAN IP and DNS
- Uninstalling all 3rd party network related software
- Network reset all settings (Windows feature)
- Safe Mode
- Adding a DHCP related DWORD to the registry that ended in “Toggle” with a value of 1
- Trying all of this with both Ethernet and WiFi
- Trying an external WiFi adapter

This is on Windows 10. Even Ping fails to transmit with “general error”.

Comment: "some network related programs were installed (since removed)" Sometimes changes from installing programs remain even after "uninstalling". You've pretty much tried everything so it must be something else broken within windows or somehow some hardware other than the network adapter or maybe the network? Can any other devices successfully connect to the network? Also maybe just try booting off a linux live CD/USB and see if you can get online to rule out hardware? If you have access to a router web gui which shows connected hosts, does the laptop appear in the list? Can you even ping 127.0.0.1?

Comment: You can try a couple of things.  (1) A new, test, Windows user profile (Account). Try to see if any difference from a new user.  (2) Try a Windows 10 Repair Install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 .  This is not a Windows Reinstall.  Try first: Keep Everything; second Keep Data  (Keep Data keeps the existing Windows User Account).

Comment: Random thoughts - try booting from a linux USB and does the network port works? (just to see if we can rule out physical damage).

Comment: @Darius the router does work with other devices and shows the laptop but I cannot ping the router. I think I tried Linux liveboot before but let me try again and report back

Comment: @John OK good ideas let me try that and I will update you